# How does Basic Authorization Attribute works in MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

Here is my action

```
[BasicAuthorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // code goes here
}
```

Now if I want access the action, I should login to the Application.
It's fine, But my question is

> How [BasicAuthorize] attribute knows the user is loggedin or not?

In my app we are storing login details in session.
Please help to understand.

Edit:
This class has no code

```
public sealed class BasicAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

And "Attribute" class is also from metadata

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350561/how-does-the-authorize-tag-work-asp-net-mvc

Comment: They have added there own code, But for me the class is empty.

    public sealed class BasicAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }